# Why does the script not work unless written on the element itself?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My files are in the same folder. When I run the jQuery commands on the html file itself or the external `script.js` file, nothing happens.

But when I make the query directly on the line itself, it works.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<!--Nothing happens -->

<script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script>
        $( "para1" ).click(function() {
            $("para1").hide();
        });
    </script>

<body>
    <p id="para1">This is a paragraph</p>
</body>


<!-- Works -->

<body>
    <p id="para1" onclick="$(this).hide();">This is a paragraph</p> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access the HTML document, but it has not been created yet. Your script executes before your document is created.

You have to wait for the HTML to be created to start assigning jquery stuff to nodes.

you need to do this: Let's define a function to be called when your document is created:

```
<script>
    function document_created() {
        // your document is created now
        // you can assign your stuff:
        $( "#para1" ).click(function() {
            $("#para1").hide();
        });
    }
</script>
```

... And now let's call it when the document has been created.

How do you know when the document has been created?

Using jquery:

```
$(document).ready(document_created);
```

Using normal DOM events:

```
<body onload="document_created()">
```

This is called "subscribing to an event". there are many other interesting events that you can subscribe as well: page unload, window resize, etc....

Also, when you use JQuery to access an element by ID, you need yo use "#" in front of the name. It may work the way you have it, but is not very correct. So:

```
$("#para1") ---> will access element with ID="para1" - ids are unique, so will be only one-
$(".para1") ---> will select elements with class "para1" - can be many-
```

Answer (score 1):

This

```
$( "para1" ).click(function() {
    $("para1").hide();
});
```

Should be

```
$( "#para1" ).click(function() {
    $("#para1").hide();
});
```

Notice the use of the `#` in the selector. This means what you type after it is an *ID*.

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery you need to use `#` as a prefix for [**id-selectors**](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/). In addition, ones inside a jQuery bound click event the context of `this` is set to the element which triggered the click event, so `$(this).hide()` will work in your case just the same inside the event handler.

change this:

```
$( "para1" ).click(function() {
    $("para1").hide();
});
```

to:

```
$("#para1").click(function() { // add the # prefix
    $(this).hide(); // use this
});
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4Dy5F/) - Using above suggested code

---